# How do I create a border for an image?

Tags: html, css, border

I want to create a colored thick border with rounded corners around an image.It would look like this:

[image: Border around image.]

How do I do this using HTML and CSS?

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: I don't know how to go about it. I have placed the image thumbnail.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I didn't know I could specifically add a border an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this, it will definitely work as you requested.

```
img {
  border: 13px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following...

```
img {
border:2px solid black;
border-radius:10px;
}
```

Modify it to what looks best for you.

Answer (score 1):

How to do this in `CSS` and `HTML`:

**CSS:**

```
.ImageBorder
{
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: Blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<img src="MyImage.gif" class="ImageBorder" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put `img` inside a wrapper div and then give a border-radius value to make a rounded border. by this technique image will also appear as a rounded.

```
.image-wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.image-wrap:after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    border: solid 3px #1b1b1b;

    -wekbit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.4), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.4), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.4), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);

    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.image-wrap img {
    vertical-align: bottom;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);

    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Here is the working Demo. http://jsbin.com/jicikalo/1/edit

Comment: @Jona please close this question by accepting the any one answer.